# Oracle Forms 10g. how to access files stored in another server

Tags: batch-file, dns, remote-server, oracleforms

I'm struggling with an Oracle issue.

I have an application developed with Oracle Forms 10g (10.1.2.3.0) hosted by Oracle Application Server 10.1.2.3.

I need to access files stored in remote servers (suppose `\\DBServer\temp directory`). In details, I should use `webutil_file_transfer.as_to_client([user's computer path],\\DBServer\temp\tempfile.txt), & also some DOS commands (eg: HOST('cmd /c move /Y \\DBServer\temp\tempfile2.txt \\OASServer\temp'))`.
`\\DBServer\temp` directory is mapped in webutil.cfg file, its shared & it has full control rights given to Everyone.

Everything worked on computers belonging to the same domain, until I had to move DBServer on a different domain & restart both OASServer & DBServer.

After I restarted both computers, the application is not able to access remote files. In details, WUT-121 error is issued (file transfer forbidden by administrator).

What is worst, is that I can not access files stored in the same domain! I mapped a \TestServer\temp directory (where \TestServer belongs to the same domain of \OASServer), but I get the same error (WUT-121). Note that the HOST command works perfectly under a DOS shell.

I suppose something were wrong during restart, but I don't know what. Does anyone know how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: dear mack,
thanks for correcting my post. a hint to resolve the issue would be appreciated too...